# Should leeway be included in the NotBefore date of an X.509 certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Which of these options are actually in line with standards?

In software that generates SSL client certificates to hand out to client software for authentication into a closed system, should the `NotBefore` field be set to *the time of generation*, or that time *subtracted by some leeway*?

The main points of concern here are:

- Clock-skew between the generating server and the authenticating server.
- Clock-skew on the client OS.
- Any vulnerabilities that arise from going too permissive on the `NotBefore` date.

The options are:

1. Include the leeway in the `NotBefore` date.
2. Don't add leeway to the `NotBefore` date but instead cater for it during validation.  (At a glance, this doesn't appear to be a common option, so likely involves hacking low-level SSL implementation on server software.)
3. Don't add leeway and handle clock-skew directly on the servers.  (This doesn't handle the client, but a small sample of APIs I looked at (namely .NET Framework) don't seem to mind choosing yet-to-be-valid certificates.)

Comment: Isn't this only a problem at the very beginning of a client certs' life cycle? How often will these client certs be replaced? If the answer is "once every 3 years" then I don't think you have to worry about notBefore too much. FWIW: Mozilla allows [*Minor tweaking for technical compatibility reasons*](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:Problematic_Practices).

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Yeah, it's an edge case in terms of life cycle, but they're replaced (auto-refreshed) by the client software every month so the result multiplied by users is possibly significant enough impact on support that I want to at minimum get a bearing on options and cost.  Very interesting link, thanks for that.